# I need guidance on how to make the tables I have made as scientific as possible, line placement and centering of numbers under headers

Tags: tables, formatting, header-footer, longtable, threeparttable

I`m currently writing a scientific paper and I need some guidance on how to make my tables as good as they possibly can be. I have just started to explore the wonders of LaTex and have therefor limited experience in how to avoid common pitfalls.

Help needed for Table 1 (The first code provided under this text)

- The fist thing I need help for is how to center the caption text above the table
- I also need some help on the layout of the table. To be more specific, I need help to decrease
  the space between the last row in the table to the line just above the table notes.
- Could someone also help me to slightly increase the space between the lines beneath the caption
  such that it doesn't appear as squished as it is at the moment.

Help needed for the second table (Table 3), (Code provided under the code of table 1)

- Can someone please help me align the numbers under the headers?

Best regards Svein

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
   
%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize

\item {\footnotesize XX = XXXXXXX XXXXX}
\item \(^a\){\footnotesize XXXX XXXXX XX}
\item \(^c\){\footnotesize  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}
\item \(^d\){\footnotesize XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}
\item \(^f\){\footnotesize XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}
\item \(^h\){\footnotesize XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}

\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{p{5.5cm} p{1.5cm} p{2cm}}
\caption{XXXXX XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXX (\textit{n}=115)}\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{Demographic characteristics} & \textbf{N(\%)} & \textbf{Mean(SD)}\\[1pt]
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX} & \textbf{N(\%)} & \textbf{Mean(SD)}\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot



\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes 
\endlastfoot
\textbf{XX ({\footnotesize XXXX})} (\textit{n}=300) & & 36.7(12.4)
\cr XXXX & XXXX  
\cr XXXX & XXXX
\cr XXXX & XXXX
\cr XXXX & XXXX
\cr $\geq$ XXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXX} (\textit{n}=300) 
\cr  Female & XXXX
\cr  Male & XXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXX} (\textit{n}=300) & & XXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXX} (\textit{n}=300) & & XXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXX\(^a\)(\(kg/m^2\))}(\textit{n}=300) & & XXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXX} (\textit{n}=100)
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX ({\footnotesize years})} (\textit{n}=XXX)
\cr  XXXXXX (XXXXXX) & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX} & XXXXXX
\cr \raggedright\textbf{XXXXXX({\footnotesize XXXXXX})} (\textit{n}=300) & & XXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX} & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXXXXX} (\textit{n}=300) & & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXXXXXX} (\textit{n}=300) & & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX\(^b\)} (\textit{n}=300)
\cr  XXXXXX& & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX & & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX XXXXXX XX & & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXX XXXX XXXXXX & & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX & & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX XXXXX & & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX\(^c\)} (\textit{n}=XXX) & & XXXXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXXX XXX\(^d\)} (\textit{n}=XX) & & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX\(^e\)} (\textit{n}=XX) & & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX} & XXXXXX
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX} (\textit{n}=XX)
\cr \textless XX\% & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX\% & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX\% & XXXXXX
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX} & XXXXXX
\cr \textless XXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr \textgreater XXXXXX & XXXXXX 
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXX} (\textit{n}=XX)
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX & & XXXXXX
\cr \raggedright\textbf{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX} (\textit{n}=XXX) & & XXXXXX 
%
\cr \textbf{XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}\raggedright(\textit{n}=XXX)
\cr  XXXXXX &  XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX
\cr  XXXXXX & XXXXXX

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

####################################################################################################################################################################################################
Second table, Table 3

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <---
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\thetable{3}
\caption{XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\begin{tabular}{ l d{2.7} d{2.6} d{2.5} }
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Spooky action at a distance}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean minutes}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SD\(^a\)}\\
\hline
  
XXX & 8.2 & 1.2  \\
  
XXX & 305.2 & 1.1  \\

XXXXX & 189.3 & 0.6 \\

XXXX & 62.3 & 0.1 \\
 
XXXX XXXX & 2.3  & 0.4 \\

XXXXX XXXXX & 39.5 & 1.2 \\
  
XXX  & 0.3 & 1.2 \\

XXXXXX XXXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.9 \\

XXXXXXXX & 8.9 & 1.4 \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXXXX XXXXXXXXX} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}
%XXXXXX XXXXXXX & & \\
%\hline
XXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.5 \\
XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX 90 & 562.3 & 2 \\
XXXX XXXXX XXXXXX 10 & 98.2 & 1.2 \\
XX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX 30 & 1.9 & 0.1 \\
XXXXXX XXXXX 10 & 90.3 & 1.5 \\
XXXXX XXXXXXX 20 & 9.8 & 1.9 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}[para]    % <---
    \footnotesize
    Abbrevations: \(^a\)SD = Standard deviation
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: For the first table, the caption is centred. Also , a longtable is automatically centred, so using the `center` environment only adds unwanted vertical spacing. For the spacing between the last row and the `\bottomrule`, remove the two blank lines between them. For the point, replace in the `firsthead` section `\hline\hline`  with `\toprule` and the following `\hline` with `\midrule`. This will add some vertical padding to the rules.

Comment: Regarding the second table: `\begin{tabular}{ l d{3.1} d{1.1} }` should get you closer to the expected output.